# How do I use trackPageView with Google Analytics (newest version)?

Tags: backbone.js, google-analytics, router

```
var url;
url = Backbone.history.getFragment();
return ga.push(['_trackPageview', "/" + url]);  // is this right?
```

I get "undefined" does not have "push".

I am using the latest version of Google Analytics and Backbone.js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Universal Analytics custom dimensions and trackpageview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255337/google-universal-analytics-custom-dimensions-and-trackpageview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for the current version (Universal Analytics) would be

[ga('send', 'pageview', '/'+url);](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)

Comment: Check this answer for a more complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32832125/1161156