# Google Analytics and Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, google-analytics

I am looking for a bit of help, I have been reading documentation on adding Analytics to backbone.js specifically this [link](http://nomethoderror.com/blog/2013/11/19/track-backbone-dot-js-page-views-with-google-analytics/) and I think I fully understand it, but my issue is do I have to add the analytic tracking code to every page I want analytic's data from, if not can you point me in the right direction.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: `every-page`? If the app is backbone, it will be a single page application.

Comment: Every view or template sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [link](http://nomethoderror.com/blog/2013/11/19/track-backbone-dot-js-page-views-with-google-analytics/) in the question, you have to include the code only once probably in the router definition file.

The router.js (the file in which `Backbone.Router` is defined) will look something like this :

```
router.js

//Include the google-analytics code here, first snippet from the code in 
//this http://nomethoderror.com/blog/2013/11/19/track-backbone-dot-js-page-views-with-google-analytics/

var router=Backbone.Router.extend({
initialize: function() {
  this.bind('route', this._pageView);
  //your custom code goes here
},

_pageView: function() {
  var path = Ba1ckbone.history.getFragment();
  ga('send', 'pageview', {page: "/" + path});
},

//Other member definitions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this Google devs guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications
Here's my version of the solution (I've added the suggested call to `ga('set'...)`before `ga('send'...)` ):

```
MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend
    ...
    initialize: () ->
        # Track every route and call trackPage
        @bind 'route', @trackPage

    trackPage: () ->
        url = Backbone.history.getFragment()
        # Add a slash if neccesary
        if not /^\//.test(url) then url = '/' + url
        # Analytics.js code to track pageview
        global.ga('set', page: url)
        global.ga('send', 'pageview')
    ...
```